# MongoDB C# Property serializing with string and int value for query

Tags: c#, mongodb, enums, mongodb-.net-driver

I'd like to query some collection of "A". Class "A" has a `Status` property which is defined like this:

```
public class Status<T> 
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)] //<- this was added some time later!
    public T Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

So `A` looks like:

```
public class A 
{
    public Status<MyEnum> Status {get; set;}
}
```

where `T` usually is an enum. I try to query it like this:

```
var f = Builders<A>.Filter.Or(
  Builders<A>.Filter.Eq("Status.Code", intStatus),
  Builders<A>.Filter.Eq("Status.Code", stringStatus)
);

filterCondition &= f;
```

Now the problem is there are older records in the DB where `Status.Code` is still an `int`. Now the query only finds the records where `Status.Code` is already stored as a string.

I don't understand the problem well enough but I suspect the driver has a hard time serializing it and thus ignores ints. Is there a way to config this, so that the query finds both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you apply the `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]` attribute, the serializer will convert the `Code` field value as `string` type.

This approach may look *ugly*, but using `BsonDocument` would be able to escape the value to be serialized as `string`.

```cs
var f = Builders<A>.Filter.Or(
    new BsonDocument("Status.Code", intStatus),
    Builders<A>.Filter.Eq("Status.Code", stringStatus)
);
```

Another approach is that pass the `intStatus` value as the `BsonValue` type.

```cs
var f = Builders<A>.Filter.Or(
    Builders<A>.Filter.Eq("Status.Code", BsonValue.Create(intStatus)),
    Builders<A>.Filter.Eq("Status.Code", stringStatus)
);
```